# Call base method in Javascript using Douglas Crockford's functional inheritance

Tags: javascript, inheritance

Basically how do I call a base method using this patter below?

```
var GS = {};
GS.baseClass = function (somedata) {
  var that = {};
  that.data = somedata;

  //Base class method
  that.someMethod = function(somedata) {
    alert(somedata);
  };

  return that;
};

GS.derivedClass = function(somedata) {
 var that = GS.baseClass(somedata);

 //Overwriting base method
 that.someMethod = function(somedata) {
   //How do I call base method from here? 

   //do something else
 };
 return that;
};
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
var GS = {};
GS.baseClass = function (somedata) {
  var that = {};
  that.data = somedata;

  //Base class method
  that.someMethod = function(somedata) {
    alert(somedata);
  };

  return that;
};

GS.derivedClass = function(somedata) {
 var that = GS.baseClass(somedata);

 //Overwriting base method
 var basemethod = that.someMethod;
 that.someMethod = function(somedata) {
   //How do I call base method from here? 
   basemethod.apply(that, [somedata]);
   //do something else
 };
 return that;
};
```

Cheers.

Comment: Anatoliy, why do I need to use .apply method in this case? if I can simply call basemethod(somedata)?

Comment: Apply will execute function "basemethod" in context of object "that", i.e. in the method "basemethod" you may use "this" - it will be links to that. If you use basemethod(somedata), function will running in global (window) context, which is incorrect in this case. Sample:
<pre>
window.myvar = 'window context var';
object = {
    myvar: 'object context var'
};
var fun = function () {
    alert(this.myvar);
}
fun();
fun.apply(object);
</pre>